# How do I get typescript to correctly infer other function arguments from a discriminatory argument?

Tags: typescript, discriminated-union

```
type ATrue = (a: true, b: number) => void;
type AFalse = (a: false, b: string) => void;

const fromUnion: ATrue | AFalse = (a, b) => {
  if (a) {
    b; // any
  } else {
    b; // any
  }
};

const fromIntersection: ATrue & AFalse = (a, b) => {
  if (a) {
    b; // number | string
  } else {
    b; // number | string
  }
};
```

typescript infers what I've written in the comments

Is there anyway to get typescript to infer that `b: number` if `a: true` and `b: string` if `a: false`?

Comment: The type `ATrue | AFalse` isn't useful since the resulting function is uncallable; not sure what you intend to do with it.  The type `ATrue & AFalse` *is* useful but the compiler is not going to be able to infer well there since it's effectively an overloaded function type...

Comment: ...You can get the desired behavior inside the function implementation if you annotate the params yourself, and then the resulting function will be assignable to both (the useless) `ATrue | AFalse` and (the useful) `ATrue & AFalse`, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WzGK1w).  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Hmm, yes that is helpful. Unfortunately, it doesn't fully help in my particular case. I'm trying to write a fully typed system for writing views in couchdb. The reduce part of the map reduce view needs to compile down to (keys,values, rereduce) => reducedValue

Comment: The rereduce term can be true or false, but then the values and keys change, because the values match the output of the reduce function if rereduce is true and match the output of the map function if rereduce is false, so the typescript function needs to infer the correct type depending on the value of this third argument

Comment: Without a [mre] of the actual issue you're facing I don't know what else to suggest.  I can write up an answer to the question as asked, or you could [edit] it to be closer to your use case (while hopefully not needing to tag it with couchdb or rererereduce which I don't know anything about )

Comment: Sure, go ahead and write up your answer please. I think it will be useful to others, and it was enlightening to me. I'll work on a minimal reproducible example tomorrow. Thanks @jcalz

Comment: Okay I'll do so when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type `ATrue | AFalse` is a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of function types and can therefore only be called with an [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of the argument types, as described in [the documentation for calling union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-3.html#improved-behavior-for-calling-union-types).  That's because the caller doesn't know if it's `ATrue` or `AFalse`, so the only way to call it is to send in arguments that would work either way.  And since the intersection of the elements of `[a: true, b: number]` and `[b: false, b: string]` produces `[a: never, b: never]`, containing the [impossible `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type), it means that you simply cannot call a function of type `ATrue | AFalse`, and it is therefore useless:

```
declare const fromUnion: ATrue | AFalse; 
// fromUnion(a: never, b: never): void
fromUnion(true, 2); // error!
fromUnion(false, ""); // error!
```

So without more information about a use case, I'd say this is not what anyone wants to use.  Furthermore it means the compiler simply won't be giving you useful inferences for the `a` and `b` parameters of any function you use to implement this.

---

On the other hand, the type `ATrue & AFalse` is an intersection of function types, which is equivalent to an [overloaded](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) function with two call signatures.  This is much more useful, since it means that a caller can choose one of the two call signatures to call, since the function is *both* an `ATrue` *and* an `AFalse` at the same time:

```
declare const fromIntersection: ATrue & AFalse;
fromIntersection(true, 2); // okay
fromIntersection(false, ""); // okay
```

Unfortunately, TypeScript's ability to manipulate overloaded function types is currently quite limited.  It will let you call such a function, but when you implement the function it doesn't understand how to infer the parameter types as anything but uncorrelated unions; it can't [narrow](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) them based on type guards the way you're expecting.  This is a missing feature of TypeScript reported at [microsoft/TypeScript#22609](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22609).

---

So neither formulation gives you the narrowing you want.

If you care about such narrowing, I'd suggest explicitly [annotating](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#parameter-type-annotations) a [destructured](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) [rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) with a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) of [tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types), which, in TS4.6 and above, will automatically [give you the narrowing you want](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-6/#cfa-destructured-discriminated-unions):

```
type Args = Parameters<ATrue> | Parameters<AFalse>
const f = (...[a, b]: Args) => {
    if (a) {
        b; // number 
        b.toFixed(1)
    } else {
        b; // string
        b.toUpperCase()
    }
}
```

And then this function can be safely assigned to your variable of either type:

```
const fromUnion: ATrue | AFalse = f; // okay, but this is still not useful

const fromIntersection: ATrue & AFalse = f; // okay
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?moduleResolution=99&target=99&jsx=0&module=1&isolatedModules=false#code/FDAuE8AcFMAIEEAqAnArnAvLAFAQwFyyhrQA0sARoQHaoC2F0yAlLBgHywBuA9gJYATANxgoceADFcAGwDOmHAVgAzGfPJVYs4n2oBzVh279hICDATI9strAAKuZLjrRQTWQB4kJTgB97js6u7l5SctDswADGPNTaKrbYAHQpANq4GgC6hPBWsoacAN7AsKWwfMqKrMVltZRCsAD0jbC0DEywJXWlFEmgPBJ8AB7QAtgAjMxdpQC+sNDhsDXd9U0t2si6etN1vf0AqpAwyADCuPLYU7UzwDfRsfHKyDx0+9R8sTko6LD+kmoKZQNZpEAAWfBsEOoAHJQLBUPJlKhpMAQU8Xm8PtQ8DRoFwmBpcfiWIReIJgOjXu9YthiOhyAAmZjAlpMZ7IACEFOeVKx2FU4XIACIhcy1vNkOyufc4nDKQBJahuZDyKKgLFfEiwABkCDC8lsQO5L0VytV6ppdLIsCZLNgPAA1rhwMa6Kb3NA1XyBepYCKxSDHc7gEA)

Answer (score 0):

Building off of what @jcalz answered, if you adjust the initial type definitions a little you can get the type narrowing directly on a typed arrow function:

```
type ATrueArgs = [a: true, b: number];
type AFalseArgs = [a: false, b: string];
type DiscriminatedFunc = (...args: ATrueArgs | AFalseArgs) => void;

const f: DiscriminatedFunc = (a, b) => {
   if (a) {
     b; // number
   } else {
     b; // string
   }
}
```